# cURL error: [35] Unsupported SSL protocol version

Tags: php, curl, ssl, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have just made my `ipn.php` file for PayPal IPN and when I tested it with PayPal Sandbox IPN simulator, my errors log outputted this error:

```
cURL error: [35] Unsupported SSL protocol version
```

Is something wrong with my php file or my website host? How can I fix it?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

add a -1 to the curl command to force using TLS and see if that works.

-1, --tlsv1

(SSL) Forces curl to use TLS version 1.x when negotiating with a remote TLS server. You can use options --tlsv1.0, --tlsv1.1, and --tlsv1.2 to control the TLS version more precisely (if the SSL backend in use supports such a level of control).

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: I typed in the command but I did not get any response, the errors log outputted: Invalid HTTP request method.

Comment: Can you provide the full command (remove any tokens or auth materials etc).  Make sure you add this right after the curl command and dont include the comma etc.